# Trouble Adding Security Scheme for Identity in NSwag OpenAPIDocument with ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 8 project and trying to set up an OpenAPI document using NSwag. I've integrated Microsoft's Identity infrastructure for authentication, and I'm having trouble configuring the security scheme correctly within the AddOpenApiDocument method provided by NSwag.

Here's my current code:

```cs
// ...

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddOpenApiDocument(doc =>
{
    doc.AddSecurity("bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
        Description = "Bearer token authorization header",
    });

    doc.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("bearer"));
});

// ...

app.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();

// This is the endpoint, which returns a 401
app.MapGet("/", (ClaimsPrincipal user) => $"Hello {user.Identity!.Name}")
    .RequireAuthorization();
```

Despite this configuration, I get a 401 (Unauthorized) from the API.

If anyone has experience with configuring NSwag and Identity for authentication within ASP.NET Core 8, I would greatly appreciate your insights or suggestions. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with a minimal example based on your codes in .net 8 with NSwag:

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'MyContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>().AddApiEndpoints();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddOpenApiDocument(doc =>
{
    doc.AddSecurity("bearer", new NSwag.OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
        Description = "Bearer token authorization header",
    });

    doc.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("bearer"));
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{   
    app.UseOpenApi();   
    app.UseSwaggerUi3();    
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.MapGroup("/identity").MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();
app.MapGet("/requires-auth", (ClaimsPrincipal user) => $"Hello, {user.Identity?.Name}!").RequireAuthorization();


app.Run();
```

When I debug:
[image]

Notice you have to type "Bearer "  manually before the token you received

Comment: Damn, I totally missed that out `Notice you have to type "Bearer " manually before the token you received`. Thanks!